# TinyMCE Not initilizing on jqueryui modal dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tinymce, modal-dialog

The Scenario:
I need to load up an external page and apply tinyMCE to the text area

The Issue:
On first click it works, however when you close the dialog and click the button again it doesn't engage tinyMCE

The Code: test.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" id="theme">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tiny_mce/jquery.tinymce.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.newbutton').button({icons: {primary: "ui-icon-plusthick"}}).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
//      $('body').css({'overflow' : 'hidden'});
        $('#newform').dialog({
            show: "puff",  
            hide: "puff", 
            resizable: false, 
            height: 500, 
            width: 800, 
            modal: true, 
            beforeClose: function(){
                if ($("textarea.tinymce").length) {
                    $('textarea.tinymce').tinymce().remove();
                };
                $(this).html(" ");

            }, 
            close: function(){
//              $('body').css({'overflow' : 'auto'});   
                $(this).html(" ");
//              $('#newform').dialog('destroy');
            }, 
            open: function(){
                $('#newform').load("test2.html", function(){
                    $('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({
                        // Location of TinyMCE script
                        script_url : 'js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',

                        // General options
                        theme : "advanced",
                        plugins : "autolink,lists,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,advlist",

                        // Theme options
                        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
                        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
                        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
                        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak",
                        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
                        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
                        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
                        theme_advanced_resizing : true

                    });
                });
            }
        });     

    });

});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<button id="newbutton" class="newbutton">New</button>
<div id="newform" class="hide" title="Title"><!-- data loaded dynamically--></div>

</body>
</html>
```

The Code: test2.html

```
<textarea class="tinymce" id="elm1" name="elm1" rows="15" cols="80" style="width: 80%">
                &lt;p&gt;
                    This is some example text that you can edit inside the &lt;strong&gt;TinyMCE editor&lt;/strong&gt;.
                &lt;/p&gt;
                &lt;p&gt;
                Nam nisi elit, cursus in rhoncus sit amet, pulvinar laoreet leo. Nam sed lectus quam, ut sagittis tellus. Quisque dignissim mauris a augue rutrum tempor. Donec vitae purus nec massa vestibulum ornare sit amet id tellus. Nunc quam mauris, fermentum nec lacinia eget, sollicitudin nec ante. Aliquam molestie volutpat dapibus. Nunc interdum viverra sodales. Morbi laoreet pulvinar gravida. Quisque ut turpis sagittis nunc accumsan vehicula. Duis elementum congue ultrices. Cras faucibus feugiat arcu quis lacinia. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Pellentesque fermentum magna sit amet tellus varius ullamcorper. Vestibulum at urna augue, eget varius neque. Fusce facilisis venenatis dapibus. Integer non sem at arcu euismod tempor nec sed nisl. Morbi ultricies, mauris ut ultricies adipiscing, felis odio condimentum massa, et luctus est nunc nec eros.
                &lt;/p&gt;
            </textarea>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much trial and error I found the issue was because the dialog had a show and hide effect! removing these made the system work, so a work around for this was to show a loading screen while tinymce was initilizing.

Code test.html : 
    
    
    
    
    Untitled Document

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.newbutton').button({icons: {primary: "ui-icon-plusthick"}}).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('body').css({'overflow' : 'hidden'});
        $('#newform').dialog({
            show: "puff",  
            hide: "puff", 
            resizable: false, 
            height: 500, 
            width: 800, 
            modal: true, 
            beforeClose: function(){
                if ($("textarea.tinymce").length) {
                    $('textarea.tinymce').tinymce().remove();
                };
                $(this).html(" ");
            }, 
            close: function(){
                $('body').css({'overflow' : 'auto'});   
                $(this).html(" ");
                $('#newform').dialog('destroy');
            }, 
            open: function(){
                $('#newform').load("test2.html", function(){
                    $(this).css({"overflow": "hidden"});
                    $('.tinymceloader').css({"position": "absolute", "height": $(this).height()-16, "width": $(this).width() - 32, "z-index": 200, "background-color": "#ffffff"});
                    setTimeout("inittinymce(); $(this).css({\"overflow\": \"auto\"});", 500);
                });
            }
        });     

    });

});
function inittinymce(){
    $('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({
                        // Location of TinyMCE script
                        script_url : 'js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',

                        // General options
                        theme : "advanced",
                        plugins : "autolink,lists,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,advlist",

                        // Theme options
                        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
                        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
                        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
                        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak",
                        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
                        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
                        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
                        theme_advanced_resizing : true

                    });
    setTimeout("$('.tinymceloader').hide();", 1000);

}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<button id="newbutton" class="newbutton">New</button>
<div id="newform" class="hide" title="Title"><!-- data loaded dynamically--></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Code test2.html:

```
<div class="tinymceloader">Loading</div>
<textarea class="tinymce" id="elm1" name="elm1" rows="15" cols="80" style="width: 80%">
                &lt;p&gt;
                    This is some example text that you can edit inside the &lt;strong&gt;TinyMCE editor&lt;/strong&gt;.
                &lt;/p&gt;
                &lt;p&gt;
                Nam nisi elit, cursus in rhoncus sit amet, pulvinar laoreet leo. Nam sed lectus quam, ut sagittis tellus. Quisque dignissim mauris a augue rutrum tempor. Donec vitae purus nec massa vestibulum ornare sit amet id tellus. Nunc quam mauris, fermentum nec lacinia eget, sollicitudin nec ante. Aliquam molestie volutpat dapibus. Nunc interdum viverra sodales. Morbi laoreet pulvinar gravida. Quisque ut turpis sagittis nunc accumsan vehicula. Duis elementum congue ultrices. Cras faucibus feugiat arcu quis lacinia. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Pellentesque fermentum magna sit amet tellus varius ullamcorper. Vestibulum at urna augue, eget varius neque. Fusce facilisis venenatis dapibus. Integer non sem at arcu euismod tempor nec sed nisl. Morbi ultricies, mauris ut ultricies adipiscing, felis odio condimentum massa, et luctus est nunc nec eros.
                &lt;/p&gt;
            </textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you close the the dialogue - you will need to shut down the tinymce instance too:

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',true,'your_editor_id');
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem solved.

```
function AddTinyMCE() {
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        theme: "modern",
        height: 180,
        plugins: [
         "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
         "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
         "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor"
        ],
            content_css: "css/content.css",
            toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | l      ink image | preview | forecolor backcolor",
            style_formats: [
            { title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b' },
            { title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: { color: '#ff0000'} },
            { title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: { color: '#ff0000'} },
            { title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1' },
            { title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2' },
            { title: 'Table styles' },
            { title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1' }
        ]
    });
}
```

and call it as follows:

```
$("#dialog-Edit").dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true,
        height: 600,
        width: 700,
        title: "Example",
        buttons: [{
            text: "Save",
            title: "Save",
            tabIndex: -1,
            click: function () {

            }
        },
        {
            text: "Cancel",
            title: "Cancel",
            tabIndex: -1,
            click: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }],
        open: function () {
            AddTinyMCE();

        },
        close: function () {
            $(this).dialog("destroy");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

if the original event using destroy `($(this).dialog("destroy");)`, the problem has been resolved it deleting TinyMCE